# WordPress wp_safe_remote_get() в offline

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо продолжить выполнение кода после неудачного выполнения функции wp_safe_remote_get() в оффлайне. 
По умолчанию функция wp_safe_remote_get() останавливает выполнение кода в оффлайне.

Comment: Ничего подобного. Функция возвращает результат запроса или WP_Error. Ищите проблему в другом месте. Покажите сообщение об ошибке в логе.

Comment: Спасибо, все верно генерируется ошибка. Перед использованием переменой добавил проверку is_wp_error(), заработало так как хотел!